# TPKeyboardAvoiding ScrollView not working?

Tags: ios

I am using [TPAvoidingScrollView](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding). whenever I assign that class to View. then view changes it position down. when I click in textField then scrolling is enable. because of that at first time some of view didn't show. before clicking in textfield.

Comment: Post some code regarding how you are adding that scrollview in your app. Seems like scrollview height issue to me.

Comment: I have added  TPAvoidingScrollView class in my project. and I have added view in storyboard and assign TPAvoidingScrollView class to that view @atulkhatri